# Using C++, Issue with converting int to char always having 3 digits

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion, int

I'm trying to convert an integer with value of `1-360` and save it as a char of value `001-360`. Examples `1 = 001`, `43 = 043`, `349 = 349`.
(If there's a better approach than char I'm all ears)

I've looked for different approaches weather using string or char[] but can't seem to get it right.

LOtrackAngle will be an int number 1-360

```
case 'q':
case 'Q':
{
    char trackAngleCHR[4];
    sprintf(trackAngleCHR, "%d", LOtrackAngle);
    ss << " 16"
       << "1" << trackAngleCHR << ""
       << "1"
       << "9";
    LOtrackAngle += 1;
    if (LOtrackAngle > 360)
    {
        LOtrackAngle = LOtrackAngle - 360;
    }
    break;
}
```

Is:

```
LOtrackAngle=248, Output is 16124819.
LOtrackAngle=34, Output is 1613419.
LOtrackAngle=7, Output is 161719.
```

Should be:

```
LOtrackAngle=7, Output is 16100719.
```

I need these to always be 8 characters long.

Comment: `sprintf(trackAngleCHR, "%d", LOtrackAngle);`->`sprintf(trackAngleCHR, "%03d", LOtrackAngle);`, as described in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)?

Comment: That `sprintf` is a recipe for a buffer overflow against a `char[4]`. Just use the ostream after setting up the proper width, align, and fill char.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius That's a pretty good answer you have there, why not post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this:

```
int main()
{
    int number = 360;
    char chars[4];
    auto str = std::to_string(number);
    str.insert(0, 3 - str.size(), '0');
    std::memcpy(chars,str.data(),str.size());

    return 0;
}
```

Using this method you could either keep the original string, or memcpy it to a char[].

EDIT: Added one liner to insert 0's if needed.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I used your fix as it adds 0's in where there are no numbers and uses streams in the solution. I'll have to read up on auto!

Comment: @ROVguy No problem. Remember to accept an answer as the correct one, so people having the same issue as you can find the solution faster.

Answer (score 4):

Since you already use streams, I recommend to use fully C++ solutions:

```
#include <iomanip> //for std::setw

case 'q':
case 'Q':
{
    ss << " 16" << "1" 
       << std::setw(3) << std::setfill('0') << LOtrackAngle
       << "1" << "9";

    LOtrackAngle += 1;
    if (LOtrackAngle > 360)
    {
        LOtrackAngle = LOtrackAngle - 360;
    }
    break;
}
```

It is not only more concise and easier to read, but also safe against buffer overflow (in case your number won't fit in buffer of length `4` for some reason, you won't get some strange UB)

Comment: Thanks Yksisarvinen. when I ran this in my code it left a gap of 1 or 2 characters in the stream instead of adding 0's. I'll have to remember setw() for future problems.

Comment: @ROVguy You're right, I forgot to change the fill character. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative that doesn't use extra strings or streams.

```
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

char* fill_char_array(char *arr, int size, int num)
{
    if ( size <= 0 )
       return arr;
    memset(arr, '0', size);  // set all positions to character 0
    arr[size-1] = 0;  // null terminate
    int index = size - 2;
    while (num > 0 && index >= 0)
    {
       arr[index] = (num % 10) + '0';  // set the digit in the array
       num /= 10;
       --index;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
    char trackAngleCHR[4];
    std::cout << fill_char_array(trackAngleCHR, 4, 38) << "\n";
    std::cout << fill_char_array(trackAngleCHR, 4, 1) << "\n";
    std::cout << fill_char_array(trackAngleCHR, 4, 534) << "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
038
001
534
```